# (Discord.js) Using the discord-buttons npm package, how can I disable a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

Using discord-buttons (https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons), how can I “Disable” a discord button? (Grey it out so only specific users can click on it)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a button by typing:

```js
button.setDisabled();
```

If you want to set multiple attributes for that button, you can do this the following way:

```js
let button = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('red')
  .setLabel('My First Button!') 
  .setID('click_to_function') 
  .setDisabled();

message.channel.send('Hey, i am powered by https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons', button);
```

> Source: https://discord-buttons.js.org/examples

Comment: The question says only specific users can use it, but that is impossible isn’t it? You can check if it’s the right user and return early if it’s not the right user though...

Comment: @MrMythical You could send this Message as an ephemeral Message, so only one Person could see it. This is the closest you can get for "disableing the button for certain peoplr"